# Palindrome detector returns true even when it's not a palindrome

Tags: java, database, eclipse, boolean, palindrome

I need to make sure that on every assignment that I do, I have to write my own original code and not copy someone else's. It seems harder than you would expect. I'm trying to write a palindrome detector as part of an assignment. The code is good, except for one problem. The output says it's true, even when it's not a palindrome and it begins and ends with the same character. May you please help me. Here is my code:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome_nr(String word){
    int beginning = 0;
    int end = word.length() - 1;

    boolean pd = true;

    for (int i = end; i>0; i--){
        if(word.charAt(0) == word.charAt(word.length()-1)){
            pd = true;
        }
        else if (word.charAt(0) != word.charAt(word.length()-i)){
            pd = false;
        }
    }

    return pd;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Is the string a palindrome or not? ");
    String test = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Answer: " + isPalindrome_nr(test));
}
```

The goal is to get the word test, which is not a palindrome, registered as false, abba, which is a palindrome, registered as true, and application, which is not a palindrome, registered as false.

Answer (score 4):

You are only comparing the first and last characters. That's not nearly enough to determine if a String is a palindrome.

You need something like this :

```
pd = true;
for (int i = end; i>=0; i--){
    if(word.charAt(i) != word.charAt(end-i)){
        pd = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

This can be further improved, since this loop would test all the pairs twice, so it's probably enough that i ends at end/2 or (end/2)+1.

Answer (score 0):

You're only checking the first and last characters. The method should look like this so that your for-loop actually does what it's supposed to:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome_nr(String word) {
    int beginning = 0;
    int end = word.length() - 1;

    boolean pd = true;

    for (int i = end; i > 0; i--) {
        // notice the use of i in here so that it will check all opposite chars
        if(word.charAt(i) == word.charAt(word.length() - 1 - i)) {
            pd = true;
        }
        else { // don't need the else-if
            pd = false;
        }
    }

    return pd;
}
```

---

Just as an extra note, there is another way to test if a string is a palindrome or not: reverse it and test if the reversed string is equal to the original string. Like this (it's a one-liner):

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
    return new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString().equals(s);
}
```

Or the longer way (reversing the string with a for-loop instead of using the [`StringBuilder#reverse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse()) method

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
    StringBuilder reverseString = new StringBuilder();

    // reverse the string
    for (int i = s.length() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        reverseString.append(s.charAt(i));
    }

    // return whether or not the reversed string is equal to the original string
    return reverseString.toString().equals(s);
}
```

Comment: You should use StringBuilder over StringBuffer. No need for synchronization overhead.

Comment: @Smith_61 Actually I meant to. Just copied the wrong word. Thanks.